# Umbraco (v7) - Shared content (with in the content) on all pages

Tags: umbraco

i'm new to umbraco CMS... trying to add some shared content within the content on all pages, for example using product price on all pages within the content. i want to keep product price in a common place (like global variable or whatever its called) and will add that anywhere within the content on any page. The product price needs to be automatically updated in all page when we change price in the common place. i have tried to use macro but its not doing well within RTE (inline issue and unable to edit) and even tried with dictionary but failed. i dont know whether there is any option/functionality in umbraco or not. please can anyone help me to sort out this..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve what you're asking is to take the approach of what is already mentioned here and make a sort of "global settings" or "shared items" somewhere in your content structure. This is where you would store your products or whatever other thing you want to reuse.

To reference this in the RTE you would then come up with some sort of convention to insert a marker like this in your RTE content: `{price:productId}`, `{productName:price}` or something similar.

What you would then do is to make sure when you output your RTE property - you pass it through a rendering method that will simply go find the product from the product ID or name and then fetch the price and simply replace the marker with that price before returning the HTML output to render. This is a bit of a dirty hack that is not really user friendly to your editors. It can however be used to do many other things than just this.

If you want to make this a bit more smooth for your editors, you should instead look into using macros - say you create a 'product data' macro. It contains a picker (preconfigured to select a product from your products folder) and a dropdown that lets you select which part of the product data you want to display. Then you simply make that macro render the product data based on the selected node and the selection in the dropdown.

If possible I would go with the second approach as it is the simplest approach for your editors to understand. There's however that one downside that it pretty much requires you to use this via an RTE (because you need to be able to insert a macro), whereas the marker-replacement approach could work in *any* type of property editor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create the pricing content you need under another content tree structure ( i normally call this settings or global settings) separate to your main website(s) tree. then on the pages you want to use it add a content picker which you can then set to go to the settings to select the pricing content you need to use.

so you set the price in the settings, and on all pages you need to use this add a picker and you can reuse that picker as many times as you want and change it in 1 place. I always have this set up on all my sites and use it for things like carousel slider etc see attached image.[image]

Comment: thanks @denford... Can we get this values within RTE?

Comment: i will give you an example... look at https://www.lipsum.com/ and there are lots "Lorem Ipsum" text repeated many times on the page... i want to change this to "Ipsum Lorem" but i dont want to find and replace on every page... i want store this in a common place (as you said we can create settings/properties) as product name and use it inside content wherever i want... when adding content using RTE and i want include the product name inside any line of content... how can i do it with RTE?

Comment: It seems to me you're talking about the repository pattern.Like this?:
https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2013/creating-reusable-code-in-mvc-apps/

Comment: @Karthik unfortunately not from  RTE, this is possible in code and from your example of Lipsum your are gona be better off with a find and replace as that value in a RTE is an html string at best. What you can do is create a dictionary item with the value(s) you want to use then when you render in do the replace using the dictionary values see here on how to get the dictionary value in code https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/78256-read-dictionary-item-in-razor. could look at the solution mentioned by jabberwocky but i have never tried it.

Comment: Also, this may be more useful than my previous post: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/macros/

Comment: @denfordmutseriwa, i agree with find and replace and it is fine if one or two pages but we have 100s of pages and also find and replace may be replaced in wrong place of content...

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yes i have already mentioned in the question, already tried with macro.. the issue with macros is, its not working properly inside RTE (like couldn't add it as inline content and couldn't edit as well means every time need to remove and re-add )... but it will give me some solution if we find a inline macro...